# How do I upgrade to C++17?

Tags: c++, c++17, atom-editor, compiler-flags

I am using Atom as my IDE, my current `__cplusplus = 201402` which is C++14 and my compiler is *g++ (GCC) 9.2.0*.

How do I upgrade to C++17 or C++20?

Everything I've searched up involves using another IDE (Microsoft Visual Studio).

Comment: `g++ -std=c++17` - https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/

Comment: and use clang-tidy to help you upgrade your code to C++17

Comment: gcc 9.2 supports the majority of C++17, but doesn't enable it by default.  Use `g++ -std=c++17` to enable support.    C++2a has partial support in gcc 9.2, and that can be enabled using `-std=c++2a`.   You'll need to upgrade to a more recent version of gcc to have more complete support of C++20 - however, at present, there isn't complete support of C++2a in gcc.

Comment: Install a compiler that has the features you need. In Linux, typically by upgrading your version of Linux. I say that because the features provided are the compiler are a gradient, not an absolute. C++14,C++17,C++20 ... its misleading. A compiler at a certain version may have some features but not all. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: Real question is: what do you use as a build manager? Feeding compiler options directly to compiler is a crude solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't "upgrade" to newer C++ standards.
You can upgrade *compiler* to newer version supporting latest standards.

As of today, most compilers are set to C++14 by default.
To change it you need to pass additional argument during compilation.

For example, to compile `hello.cpp` with GCC for C++17 you need to execute

```
g++ -std=c++17 hello.cpp
```

You need to check how to pass compiler flags (or set standards) in your IDE / editor / build system.

---

I'm not familiar with Atom, but I've found [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-set-compiler-flags-in-c-with-atom/68821):

> In the settings, click on *Packages*, then search for `gpp-compiler`. You should see a settings button – click on it and edit the command line options to suit your needs.

Answer (score 7):

Do-it-yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    std::cout << __cplusplus;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile this firstly with the following command:

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp && ./main
```

Thereafter:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -std=c++17 && ./main
```

You'll get to know the differences. **Note that if you're unable to use `-std=c++20` flag, it clearly means that your compiler doesn't supports C++20 standard.**